# X and Y coordinates not correct if the div doesn't fit on the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to retrieve the X and Y coordinates from a div. My div doesn't fit on the screen and if I use the slide bar to click on the bottom of the screen the coordinates are not correct. How can I fix that

```
$(function () {
    $("#overlayDiv").click(function (e) {

        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
        var relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top);

        alert("X: " + relativeX + "  Y: " + relativeY);
    });
});

<div id="pdfDiv">
             <div id ="overlayDiv"></div>
             <iframe class="iFrameClass" id="pdfForm"  src="{{pdfFile}}" width="940" height="1260"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear why exactly you believe the value to be wrong, but try `clientX` or `offsetX`, along with the associated `Y` methods.

Comment: so adjust to use the scroll position

Comment: You might want to try `var y = this.getBoundingClietRect().top + document.body.scrollTop; var x = this.getBoundingClietRect().left + document.body.scrollLeft` for the absolute coordinates of an object on a scrolled page.